# Forcing inline with a single macro in GCC, Clang and Intel Compiler?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, icc

I have a function that I need inlined in a tight loop in C++11

I want the function to be implemented in a separate file from the header and still force the it to be inlined everywhere it is used. Also, I want to compile with both clang, GCC and the Intel compiler.

To flesh out the requirement. I am looking for a macro that would allow me to do something like:

```
#define force_inline <something here>
```

In headers:

```
force_inline void foo();
```

And I should be able to do this in the implementation file:

```
void foo() {... Code.. }
```

Just to be clear, I do not want to put code in my headers. I want them to only contain the declaration of the function.

Is there a way to achieving inlining with a macro that works on all those compilers?

The best solution I have so far is this macro:

```
#define forceinline inline __attribute__((always-inline))
```

It seems that ICC needs both `inline` (which has nothing to do with inlining the code) and the full implementation in the header to guarantee inlining of the function.

PS: Yes, I have measured my performance and I know for a fact that it is faster to have the function inlined than not. And no, the compiler does not do it for me.

Comment: Use `gcc -flto -O2` both for compiling and linking. or better just define your function as `static inline` in your header file.

Comment: Too many answers? I am looking for the macro that works on all three compilers at the same time.

Comment: Macros are not useful for inlining.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That won't work on Clang I am pretty sure. What goes in the body if you static inline in the header?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Putting a `static inline` function in your header does work on Clang and on GCC. Please edit your question to show some real source code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: But they are useful for providing a shorthand modifier on the function that can change by compiler.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Just to be clear: I do NOT want the implementation of the function in the header, only the declaration

Comment: Why? You should put the definition of your function in the header. Otherwise, you want `-flto -O2` but it is very compiler specific. Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Why? Because I don't want code floating around in headers. I want my headers to be headers, not implementation files.

Comment: You cannot have that (except with `-flto -O2`). And link-time optimization has drawbacks: it is *very* sensitive to compiler and version (and it slows down build time).

Comment: This is plainly answerable, even if the answer is "no".

Comment: @Thomas I understand that desire, really I do, but this may be one of those times that it's a net positive going against your preference.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thanks :) The closest I have gotten is #define forceinline inline __attribute__((always-inline))... This does the trick as long as all code remains in headers. But it is filthy

Comment: Per N4140 [dcl.fct.spec]/4: "An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same definition in every case (3.2)." It's easier to avoid ODR violations if you put a single definition in a header file and include it in every TU that ODR-uses it. Copying the definition into multiple implementation files will of course have the same effect, but I think it's even more filthy.

Comment: @Casey: He's not marking the function `inline`; he wants it to be _inlined_. There is a huge difference.

Comment: @Casey: As per Lightness, I want to forcing inlining, not have a copy in every translation unit that includes the header (though that follows from me requiring it to be inlined)

Comment: You want modules in C++; they are not yet standardized, but people are proposing them. Perhaps for C++17 or later!

Comment: Why not just put the implementation in a separate C file and #include that in the header?  You will have to rebuild any source that inlines the function if you change it anyway.

Comment: @Marty: Relying on link time inlining with CLANG, I don't have to rebuild the all sources if I only change the implementation of the function and not the header. Unfortunately, the same is not true for ICC.

Comment: @ThomasKejser: I, too, understand the desire to have only the declarations in header files. But once you get to the point where you are writing templates, you're out of luck anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, an inline function has its code included (by the compiler) at each place it's called.

It means the compiler needs to be able to access the function's code when it builds the callers compilation unit. This is technically feasible, but not easy and hardly scalable. Note that if you distribute only your header and a library, it means the compiler using your component has to retrieve the code from the library !!

If implemented by a compiler, it means that you won't benefit from having code out of header as much as for regular functions (changing the CPP file will require recompiling all the files depending on the header, even if it didn't change). The only benefit would be to have a header that doesn't contain code (which is still a good thing).

The only currently available solution that I'm aware of is the link time optimization of GCC, therefore not meeting your requirement of working with clang and icc: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization
Maybe something similar exists for those compiler with specific options, which would need to do compiler dependant code to support it.

**Solution 1:**
You could keep a "clean class" without any implementation in the header and put the inline functions outside of the class (but still inside the header). You still have definitions in the header but it's clearly separated from the declaration so it hurts less the readability. (This is my prefered solution personally)

**Solution 2:**
Another way to mitigate your issue, if you really want only the declarations in the header, is to separate your code in 3 files instead of 2:
 - a .h file containing only the interface
 - a .i file containing inline functions and included by the .h file
 - a .cpp/.cc file containing the rest of the code

Obviously this has drawbacks too as your code is now separated in two different files ...

Please tell me if you see an issue that I missed and that you see in these propositions.